I feel like Google suddenly shadow-banned my website (even though Google Search Console says its indexed)
I have been a web developer for many years, but I cannot figure out what's going on.
I have a website for a free side software project I am running called "sq uiso" (squi so.com).
The domain is registered in Google Search Console, and I have no security or any other problems in Google Search Console:

However, I noticed around 17th November, all "search impressions" died.

And the number of indexed pages just dropped:

However, if you do site:squ iso.com you can do see that Google does have indexed some pages:

However, if you search on "squ iso", not a single page from that domain appears.
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22squi so%22
That's incredible! With such a unique name, a .com domain and even the top results points towards .com - Google is not displaying a single page.
However, if I search on "squ iso twitch" - It becomes first search result.

And to make things even weirder - Bing is acting as expected:
https://www.bing.com/search?q=squi so
My question is; Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be going on?

A large percentage of your pages were un-indexed in Nov. Are there any similarities with the pages that aren't indexed? Missing keep meta for organic signals? Are canonicals set properly?

Google makes core updates multiple times a year. They dropped one in November 2024 and I suspect you were hit hard from that.
You can view their timeline of core updates and figure out if this might be the cause of your decreased rankings.
A lot of the main SEO players have guides if you believe you were negatively impacted by core updates: SearchEngineLand.com, SearchEngineJournal.com.
This could also be a good time to do some keyword analysis to better improve your content for ranking purposes. Look what what keywords you are showing for and deciding if those are the best terms. Adjust the content and meta to target different keywords to better achieve your goals.
SearchEngineJournal.com also keeps a page dedicated to core updates to help people stay on top of the changes.

Ah ok, yeah - maybe it's because of the core update :)
